# Kubernetes HPA changing sync period

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am trying to change the sync period as mentioned in the [following k8s document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/). I found the file named `kube-controller-manager.yaml` in /etc/kubernetes/manifests. I changed the `timeoutSeconds:` value from 15 secs(default) to 60 secs. Now I have 2 questions based on above info:

- 1. Is this the right way to change the sync period ? Cause I have read in the document that there is some flag named `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period`,  but adding that is also not working.
- 2. And any changes made to the file `kube-controller-manager.yaml` are getting restored to default whenever I restart the minikube? what should I do? Please let me know any solution or any view in this.

Comment: Hello @Museb Momin, welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question by adding `kube-controller-manager.yaml` file. Do you really change `timeoutSeconds:` value? - "The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is implemented as a control loop, with a period controlled by the controller manager's --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period flag (with a default value of 15 seconds)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the sync period you have to run following command while starting the minikube.
minikube start --extra-config 'controller-manager.horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period=10s'